# How to set the right index(es) or write the right query in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, indexing, left-join

I have a table with unique index on (col1, col2, col3)

I have a query on this table with

```
...
left join my_table t on t.col1=x.col1 and t.col2=x.col2 and t.col3 in (1,2,3)
```

When the list for col3 has only one item, the explain shows a `eq_ref join`

```
+----+-------------+----------+------------+--------+---------------+-----+---------+---------------------+------+----------+-------+
| id | select_type |  table   | partitions |  type  | possible_keys | key | key_len |         ref         | rows | filtered | Extra |
+----+-------------+----------+------------+--------+---------------+-----+---------+---------------------+------+----------+-------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | my_table | NULL       | eq_ref | veh           | veh |       8 | x.col1,x.col2,const |    1 |   100.00 | NULL  |
+----+-------------+----------+------------+--------+---------------+-----+---------+---------------------+------+----------+-------+
```

But with two or more items, the index is not used anymore

```
+----+-------------+----------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+----------+----------+------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type |  table   | partitions | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  |   rows   | filtered |                     Extra                      |
+----+-------------+----------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+----------+----------+------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | my_table | NULL       | ALL  | veh           | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 13705314 |   100.00 | Range checked for each record (index map: 0x3) |
+----+-------------+----------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+----------+----------+------------------------------------------------+
```

An additional non unique index on col3 doesn't help
How can I set the index(es) that can be used by such a `join` condition ?

Or how can I rewrite the query ?

---

*Edit: additionnal info*

```
explain format=json
select x.*,ifnull(group_concat(t.col4 separator ','),'') col4
from
  (select col1,col2,total from tmp_data limit 10) x
  left join my_table t on t.col1=x.col1 and t.col2=x.col2 and t.col3 in (38,85)
group by x.col1,x.col2
order by x.total desc

{
 "query_block": {
   "select_id": 1,
   "cost_info": {
     "query_cost": "411271.71"
   },
   "ordering_operation": {
     "using_temporary_table": true,
     "using_filesort": true,
     "grouping_operation": {
       "using_filesort": true,
       "nested_loop": [
         {
           "table": {
             "table_name": "x",
             "access_type": "ALL",
             "rows_examined_per_scan": 10,
             "rows_produced_per_join": 10,
             "filtered": "100.00",
             "cost_info": {
               "read_cost": "10.50",
               "eval_cost": "2.00",
               "prefix_cost": "12.50",
               "data_read_per_join": "240"
             },
             "used_columns": [
               "col1",
               "col2",
               "total"
             ],
             "materialized_from_subquery": {
               "using_temporary_table": true,
               "dependent": false,
               "cacheable": true,
               "query_block": {
                 "select_id": 2,
                 "cost_info": {
                   "query_cost": "12.50"
                 },
                 "table": {
                   "table_name": "tmp_data",
                   "access_type": "ALL",
                   "rows_examined_per_scan": 10,
                   "rows_produced_per_join": 10,
                   "filtered": "100.00",
                   "cost_info": {
                     "read_cost": "10.50",
                     "eval_cost": "2.00",
                     "prefix_cost": "12.50",
                     "data_read_per_join": "5K"
                   },
                   "used_columns": [
                     "col1",
                     "col2",
                     "total"
                   ]
                 }
               }
             }
           }
         },
         {
           "table": {
             "table_name": "t",
             "access_type": "ALL",
             "possible_keys": [
               "veh",
               "col3"
             ],
             "rows_examined_per_scan": 13705314,
             "rows_produced_per_join": 320380,
             "filtered": "100.00",
             "range_checked_for_each_record": "index map: 0x3",
             "cost_info": {
               "read_cost": "347183.21",
               "eval_cost": "64076.00",
               "prefix_cost": "411271.71",
               "data_read_per_join": "7M"
             },
             "used_columns": [
               "col1",
               "col2",
               "col3",
               "col4"
             ]
           }
         }
       ]
     }
   }
 }
}

create table tmp_data 
(col1 mediumint(1) unsigned not null default 0,
 col2 mediumint(1) unsigned not null,
 total decimal(11,0) not null default 0,
 key veh (col1,col2) using hash
) engine=memory default charset=latin1 collate=latin1_general_ci

create table my_table
(col1 mediumint(1) unsigned not null,
 col2 mediumint(1) unsigned not null,
 col3 smallint(1) unsigned not null,
 col4 text collate latin1_general_ci,
 unique key veh (col1,col2,col3),
 key col3 (col3)
) engine=myisam default charset=latin1 collate=latin1_general_ci
```

Comment: What version of MySQL?  (Improvements in the Optimizer have been made; don't know if any would help your particular situation.)

Comment: The version is 5.7.19

Comment: Hmm... Let's see `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...` plus the `SHOW CREATE TABLEs`

Comment: Requested info appended in the question

Answer (score 0):

1. Use InnoDB, not MyISAM or MEMORY.  Most Optimizer improvements have gone only into InnoDB.  (Caveat: I do not have proof that this will help.)
2. While making that change, change the unique key to `PRIMARY KEY (col1,col2,col3)`.  The "clustered" nature of InnoDB's PK should help further.  (This change will have no impact in MyISAM.)